# jQuery: recommendations on the jQuery Ribbon plugins out there?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, ribbon

I see there are several jQuery plugins out there that attempt to reproduce the Ribbon (Fluent) UI that Microsoft introduced with Word 2007:

[image]

The ones I found include:

- http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-ribbon/
- http://dev.mikaelsoderstrom.se/scripts/jquery/ribbon/

Any experiences with either of these?  recommendations for or against?

Comment: It is kinda sad that even in 2013 there is no **good** Ribbon jquery widget out there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried using this, but did not show up correctly, menu would stay showed up, and when i finally got it to hide, when i click it would hide instantly.. so i gave up on it for now

Answer (score 4):

You can go for http://jqueryribbon.codeplex.com/
It is the best one.

Answer (score 0):

I rather this implementation

http://rogerpincombe.com/ribbon

it's lightweight and clear in my opinion