# Is there an implementation of a ribbon in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am looking for a ribbon in jQuery.

(see question [jQuery: recommendations on the jQuery Ribbon plugins out there?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2510625/jquery-recommendations-on-the-jquery-ribbon-plugins-out-there))

All the links seem to be dead.

Any recommendation?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: recommendations on the jQuery Ribbon plugins out there?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2510625/jquery-recommendations-on-the-jquery-ribbon-plugins-out-there)

Comment: The first link in the question seems fine.. direct link to the source http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-ribbon/source/browse/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out http://jqueryribbon.codeplex.com/

Best one I've found, although in the end we ended up rolling our own (with a lot less features).